# What are the equivalents of Microsoft ASP.NET and Visual Studio for Linux?

Tags: asp.net, linux, visual-studio

I just wonder what are the similar frameworks and tools for Linux web development.

And can I use Visual Studio to develop websites for Linux Apache? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web development on Linux isn't specifically tied to one programming language, framework or IDE. More commonly they are related in terms of being Free and Open Source (free as in cost, and also the ability to do what you want with the code).

I loved Visual Studio when we used it for classes, however I haven't quite found a tool that is the same. The only thing near to this would be Eclipse or Netbeans.

In general, many Linux enthusiasts use emacs or vi (or vim) for their editing. At first glance you may not see the power they have, but emacs is definitely a wonderful editor, and vi is very good once you become familiar with it.

For Web programming langauges and frameworks, you have a variety to pick from.

[Python](http://www.python.org/) is one of the most popular languages to use for Web development. This language has been used by Google, Reddit, Quora and a host of others. Perhaps the most popular framework for Python is Django, and each (Python and Django) have their own following, as well.

[Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/) is a wonderfully beautiful langauge, too. Most likely you may have heard of Ruby on Rails, which is a great Web framework allowing you to quickly turn an idea into something actual in no time.

PHP is another popular language, and has the PEAR framework. Many of the online forums that you can buy are written in this language, such as vBulletin and the ever famous phpbb.

In my opinion, it depends on what you want to accomplish. Python and Ruby are great for Web development, as well as non-Web, too.

Answer (score 3):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) (it [supports](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) ASP.NET) and [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1) There are several IDEs. I prefer eclipse, no matter if for html, php, python, c or java.

Ad 2) Yes you can. Create your websites, copy them to your /var/www (or wherever your ww-root) is and you are set.

EDIT: < personal opinion > By the way, I mean there is no thing like "windows web development" and "linux web development". In the end it is of no importance at all on which OS you developped your web application, on which OS the web server runs, which OS the client has or which server- and client-side languages you used (as long as you don't use something certain clients can't provide). You have a web server that communicates via HTTP, HTTPS (or whatever) with clients. This server passes certain data via CGI, lib-apache2-mod-XYZ, WSGI, the interface IIS uses for ASP (or whatever) to executable scripts. These yield a result that the web server then publishes via (fill in arbitrary OSI layer 7 protocol) to the client, no matter what the content: HTML, CSS, images, JSON, you name it. Your operating systems has nothing to do with this.
Not all interfaces are available on all hosting server OS, but you always have a bunch to choose from and what counts is the result in the end. Quidquid agis, prudenter agas et respice finem. < /personal opinion >

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton. You can use mono for ASP.NET that runs on Apache. There are even other languages. PHP, JSP, Djanjo, Ruby on Rails, Node... just to name a few languages/frameworks. There isn't a build of Visual Studio for Linux and you would be hard pressed to set it up to compile Linux assemblies on Windows.